# I want to sum Amount and Count No. of rows in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table like this

```
id  productName amount
1      Abc       10
2      xyz       20
3      Abc       10
4      Abc       10
5      Abc       10
6      Abc       10
7      xyz       20
8      xyz       20
9      xyz       20
10     xyz       20
```

I want to sum Amount and Count No. of rows for each products in mysql. Output like below

```
productName noQty   totalAmount
 ABC         5        50
 xyz         5        100
```

Comment: `SELECT productName, COUNT(*) AS noQty, SUM(amount) AS totalAmount FROM tab GROUP BY productName` **And for future please make elementary research first.**

Answer (score 0):

```
select product_name,sum(amount)as totalamount,count(productName)as noQty
from table_name 
group by productname
```

Answer (score 0):

by using count you can get [COUNT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html) from your table and using [SUM](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html) you can get sum of all same product name.

```
SELECT productName, 
count(productName) AS noQty, 
SUM(amount) AS totalAmount
FROM tableName 
GROUP BY productName
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select productname,count(productname) as qty,sum(amount) 
from table_name 
group by productname
```